# ansible - /bin/sh cd path no such file or directory

Tags: shell, ansible

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.6.3
```

Meeting a weird problem here. Having my ansible execute this task:

```
- name: Print environemnts
  shell: cd some/absolute/path && \
        env > .env && \
        docker-compose pull && \
        docker-compose up -d
  become_user: "{{ user }}"
```

results in this error thrown

`{"changed": true, "cmd": "cd /some/absolute/path && env > .env && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d", "delta": "0:00:00.004041", "end": "2019-02-24 15:15:53.343123", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-02-24 15:15:53.339082", "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /some/absolute/path: Not a directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /some/absolute/path: Not a directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

I am pretty sure the directry actually exists! Have already checked counteless times with the existence of the directory in the targeted server.

The ssh-user I'm executing this task is a `centos` user, with sudo privileges on a Centos7 server. The user var in `become: " {{user}} "` is actually another user meant to run the docker container, which imo doesnt make sense if its related to the `cannot find dir` error.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the target IP and the path. The error is clear.

> "/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /some/absolute/path: Not a directory"

"/some/absolute/path" is present, but it's not a directory

You can test it in an empty directory

```
# cd test
cd: test: No such file or directory
# touch test
# cd test
cd: test: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit offtopic, but if u use chdir parameter of shell module u can trim your shell command.